# Excel VBA variable value equal to formula

Tags: excel, vba, variables, formula

I'm struggling with assigning variable values in VBA.  I understand how to set myVar equal to an ActiveCell.Value like this:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[1]:RC[7])"
myVar = ActiveCell.Value
MsgBox (myVar)
```

Is it possible to set myVar equal to a formula and skip the ActiveCell.Value line.  I've tried this, but it does not work.

```
myVar = "=SUM(RC[1]:RC[7])"
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what is a wider scope of your goal therefore I present idea which could be useful. However, it switches from relative reference of `FormulaR1C1` into relative reference of `Range.Offset()` techniques.

```
myVar = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7)))
MsgBox myVar
```

Comment: Thanks Kaz Jaw.  That's what I was looking for.  I'm working on a  few macros and trying to get some basics down.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You start with setting the `myVar` variable first, then apply it to a range (ActiveCell or any other Range object).

```
Dim myVar as String
Dim r as Excel.Range

Set r = ActiveCell

myVar = "=SUM(RC[1]:RC[7])"
r.FormulaR1C1 = myVar
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need your formula to be relative to the active cell, you can also use the short `[..]` to evaluate a statement, e.g.:

```
MsgBox [SUM(B1:B7)]
```